# How to ask dnsmasq to not allot few IPs

Tags: networking, linux-networking, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

I am running DHCP server using dnsmasq. My DHCP server is configured to provide IP address from a subnet (say 192.168.49.0/24 with a gateway ip of 192.168.49.1)

What i now want is that the DHCP server should not allot few IP from this subnet range. As an example, if i want to reserve IP address from 192.168.49.10-15. How do we do it?

Comment: I checked the dnsmasq.conf file where one can specify something like this
dhcp-range=192.168.0.0/29,static

Comment: This will not allot IPs in this range[], but because my range is outside, i was wondering how to do it?